# Не могу понять часть кода

Tags: c++

Изучаю с++ по книге Майкла Доусона, не могу понять конкретно эти строки:

Функция computerMove(), игра крестики нолики, глава 6

```
unsigned int move = 0;
bool found = false;
while(!found && move < board.size())
{
    if(isLegal(move, board))
    {
        board[move] = computer;
        found = winner(board) == computer;
        board[move] = EMPTY;
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        ++move;
    }
}
```

//фрагмент из книги

Сначала я перебираю в цикле все возможные варианты хода от 0 до 8. Проверяю, не противоречит ли каждый из ходов правилам. Если ход допустим правила
ми, то я ставлю фигуру компьютера в выбранную клетку и проверяю, приводит ли
такой ход компьютер к победе. Если этот ход не дает победы, пробую поставить
фигуру в следующую свободную клетку. Однако если ход привел компьютер к по
беде, то цикл завершается. Я нашел ход (found равно true ), который должен сделать
компьютер (занять клетку номер move), чтобы победить.
//

Как именно показано в коде как фигура компьютера ставится в следующую свободную клетку? Я вижу только то, что клетка которую выбрал компьютер обнуляется. Помогите пожалуйста, уже давно не могу понять! И что делает конкретно это условие:

if (!found)

{

++move;

}

Ссылка на книгу: https://readli.net/izuchaem-c-cherez-programmirovanie-igr/
206 страница

Comment: Вам понятно, что делает вот эта `found = winner(board) == computer;` строчка?

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что цикл перебирает все точки в некоем board. Каждую точку сначала проверяет на валидность (isLegal). Если точка валидная - что-то происходит. Скорее всего это и есть код, отвечающий за перемещение. Без контекста с первого взгляда не понять точнее. При этом found выставляется в true и цикл прерывается. Если же точка не валидная, то повторяем, при этом увеличивая переменную move, которая, скорее всего, отвечает за текущую позицию.

Другими словами, цикл перебирает весь board и увеличивает move, пока не найдет точку, для которой isLegal вернет true

Answer (score 0):

> Сначала я перебираю в цикле все возможные варианты хода от 0 до 8. Проверяю, не противоречит ли каждый из ходов правилам. Если ход допустим правила ми, то я ставлю фигуру компьютера в выбранную клетку и проверяю, приводит ли такой ход компьютер к победе. Если этот ход не дает победы, пробую поставить фигуру в следующую свободную клетку. Однако если ход привел компьютер к по беде, то цикл завершается. Я нашел ход (found равно true ), который должен сделать компьютер (занять клетку номер move), чтобы победить.

Тут у вас как-бы всё написано.

- `isLegal(move, board)` это проверка на соответствие правилам.
- `board[move] = computer` фигура компьютера ставится в выбранную клетку.
- `winner(board)` эта функция сообщает, кто будет победителем при данном ходе.
- `winner(board) == computer` данное условие говорит о том, приведёт ли данный ход к победе компьютера.
- `board[move] = EMPTY` удаляет фигуру компьютера из выбранной клетки
- `!found` проверяет был ли найден выиграшный ход, т.е. равно ли выражение `winner(board) == computer` true
- `++move` переходит к следующей клетке, если выиграшный ход не был найден
- `!found && move < board.size()` это условие означает, что цикл будет продожаться пока не будет найден выиграшный ход или move не дойдёт до последней клетки.

Единственное, в данной функции не очень понятно, что будет происходить, если выиграшного хода нет...